# What is the correct way to fix "variable ... will not stay shared at ..."?

Tags: perl, scope

I'm trying to use this [tool](http://emu.at.mt.ut.ee/u/hansen/jswog/doc/swog.pl_en.html). (Perl version) However, when I try to run it using the recommended command `perl bin/SWOG.pl --input=examples/simple.swog --toPng=simple`, it displays the following warning (added `use diagnostics` hoping it would shed some light on how to fix it)

> `Variable "$np" will not stay shared at (re_eval 8) line 2 (#1)`
>
> (W closure) An inner (nested) named subroutine is referencing a
>       lexical variable defined in an outer named subroutine.
>
> When the inner subroutine is called, it will see the value of
>       the outer subroutine's variable as it was before and during the *first*
>       call to the outer subroutine; in this case, after the first call to the
>       outer subroutine is complete, the inner and outer subroutines will no
>       longer share a common value for the variable.  In other words, the
>       variable will no longer be shared.
>
> This problem can usually be solved by making the inner subroutine
>       anonymous, using the sub {} syntax.  When inner anonymous subs that
>       reference variables in outer subroutines are created, they
>       are automatically rebound to the current values of such variables.

I've done my due diligence to Google: [link](http://perl.apache.org/docs/general/perl_reference/perl_reference.html), but still do not understand how to apply this in my case.

I've also went back to the [source](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/prog3/ch05_10.htm) of the code snippet causing this issue. The snippet is produced again below for easy reference:

```
    # parentheses balance pattern
    # @ http://www.unix.org.ua/orelly/perl/prog3/ch05_10.htm
    $np= qr{
       \(
       (
       (?:
          (?> [^()]+ )    # Non-parens without backtracking
        |
          (??{ $np })     # Group with matching parens
       )*
       )                    
       \)
    }x;
```

I am of the opinion that the nested `$np` within the definition of this same variable `$np` is causing this warning.

Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have something like

```
sub f {
   my $np;
   $np = qr/...(??{ $np }).../;
}
```

`(??{...})` captures the lexical therein when the pattern is compiled.

In your case, because the pattern is constant, the regex pattern in the `qr//` is compiled when the `qr//` itself is compiled. Unfortunately, a new `$np` is be created every time the function runs.

You can fix the problem by avoiding lexical variables.

```
sub f {
   local our $np;
   $np = qr/...(??{ $np }).../;
   ... /$np/ ...
}
```

Or by forcing the regex pattern to be compiled when the qr// is executed by making the pattern it variable.

```
sub f {
   my $var = '';
   my $np;
   $np = qr/...(??{ $np })...$var/;
   ... /$np/ ...
}
```

But why execute `qr//` repeatedly for a constant pattern? The best solution is to move the pattern out of the sub.

```
my $np;
$np = qr/...(??{ $np }).../;

sub f {
   ... /$np/ ...
}
```

Comment: your first suggestion on using `local our` instead of `my` works. however I can't seem to get your next suggested fix to work. the original form is `$np = qr{...(??{ $np })...}x;`, wrapped in a `sub parse_tree { }` -- what shall I change this to?

Comment: is the trailing `x` in `$np = qr{...}x;` equivalent to your $var?

Comment: No, the point is to make the pattern non-constant to prevent the optmisation that makes it so it's only compiled once.

Comment: what's the syntax for doing that, ie. "make the pattern non-constant...so it's only compiled once" sorry for being thick.

Comment: You mean "make the pattern non-constant...so it's compiled every time qr// is executed", and it's done by using a variable inside the pattern, but outside of `(?{ })` and `(??{ })`

Comment: yep, perfect...all your suggested fixes work! thanks

Comment: All of these fixes are needlessly complex: To achieve recursion, the `(??{ $np })` can be replaced by `(?R)` or `(?0)`.

Comment: [`(?R)`/`(?0)`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#(%3f_PARNO_)-(%3f-_PARNO_)-(%3f%2b_PARNO_)-(%3fR)-(%3f0)) was added in [5.10.0](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5100delta.html#Recursive-Patterns), so you would have to implement it using `(??{ $np })` on 5.8 or earlier.

Comment: @amon, A second note, `(?R)`/`(?0)` recurses the entire pattern, but this is a subpattern. The correct number may not be known.